# WAPGUIDE: when i run command (CreateParcelsTask) i get error: CS0246

Tags: asp.net, mapguide

In MapGuide Maestro 6.0a3 I did the following:

1. Create custom command from file CreateParcelsTask.aspx.
2. Add custom command CreateParcelsTask.

   **I am using MAPGUIDE 4.0 review 4**
3. Start Mapguide
4. Start custom command.
   When I run the command CreateParcelsTask I get an error:
   Compiler Error Message: CS0246: The type or namespace name 'UtilityClass' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Line 4:      String sessionId = Request.Form.Get("SESSION");

=> errar line "Line 5:      UtilityClass utility = new UtilityClass();"

Line 6:      utility.InitializeWebTier(Request);

I found the file UtilityClass.cs in folder - ..\www\dotnetviewersample\Parcels\App_Code
but i don't know how to import it into CreateParcelsTask.aspx.

Тhanks in advance